# Flash Input Masks (AS3)

Tags: flash, cs3

Does anybody know how to implement input masks for flash textfields? (AS3)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [TextField restrict](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict) property

Not as glamorous as a true input mask, but gets the job done on restricting input

Answer (score 0):

Flash's TextField class doesn't support input masks (the flex TextInput class does however).

What you probably need to do is create a [regular expression](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000112.html) to validate against

You could listen to the Event.CHANGE of the TextField and run some code that trys to match the string against your regular expression.  If it matches it's valid, if it doesn't you notify the user somehow.